# Does the my commit message editor have to launch a new instance if I want Git to use it?

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm using my own editor as my Git `core.editor` that I often have open and running already. When I use it to edit a commit message, for example after

```
git commit # no message specified
```

the default message is opened into my editor correctly, as `COMMIT_MSG`, but the commit proceeds aborts before I've done anything in the editor. Similarly, an automatic merge opens `MERGE_MSG`, but the merge completes with the default message before I've had a chance to edit it.

Can I use an editor that is *already running* to edit commit messages in this way? Does the Git invocation of the message editor require a new instance in order to respond to my edits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git` waits for the invoked program to exit (with a clean exit status) and then continues. In your case the editor directly exits (and shows the content in the already existing window), which is not what `git` expects.

To solve the problem you need your editor to exit only when you finished editing the file provided by git (which, most likely, means to turn off attaching to an already existing instance).

Comment: Is there a general way to prevent Git from using an existing instance?   Failing that, perhaps there is even a shell- (`bash`) OS- (OS X) or tool- (BBEdit and TextWrangler) specific one?

Comment: You cannot blame `git` for this. Git just starts the command `someEditor`. This editor then decides what to do, in this case it exits and delegates the work to another instance. You need to tell the editor to stop doing this (maybe globally, maybe with an argument that can be added to the configuration of `git`).

Comment: For BBEdit/TextWrangler it looks like the trick is to set `core.editor` to `bbedit --wait` or `edit --wait` respectively. That launches into any running instance, but waits for the file to close before proceeding. For good measure `--resume` can be added as well, which will bring the command line window back to the front after the file is closed.

Answer (score 2):

It's down to your editor. The protocol git (and most other other things which make use of the EDITOR variable) uses is to open $EDITOR pointing to a temporary file, wait for the editor process to exit, then use the contents of the temporary file.

For TextMate, for example, setting EDITOR (or git's core.editor) to '/path/to/mate -w' will tell it to wait until the file is closed before exiting the mate helper process. Your editor may have something similar.